# After update to neo4j 4.2 not work apoc functions from reader role

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

neo4j version 4.2.0

apoc version 4.2.0.0

After update to neo4j 4.2 not work apoc functions from reader role, return error:

> message: Executing a user defined function is not allowed for user
> 'User' with roles [PUBLIC, reader].

Yes, it's qute simple just find in docs need to run script for grant privileges:

```
GRANT EXECUTE FUNCTION apoc.* ON DBMS TO reader
```

But here start real problems it's return error:

> This operation is not supported while running in compatibility mode
> with version Neo4j 4.1

Can't find anything about this *compatibility* in google or in config, run with spicifig cypher version like this not help:

```
CYPHER 4.2 GRANT EXECUTE FUNCTION apoc.* ON DBMS TO reader
```

Comment: Is the error exactly the same when you force the Cypher version in the query?

Comment: Yes, then I force Cypher version error exactly same.